# Hibernate programmatic configuration not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, orm

When I use hibernate.properties file I can successfully create a SessionFactory from my Configuration object:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .addAnnotatedClass(WeatherResponse.class);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

However instead of hibernate.properties I want to use typesafe config library in order to be able to pass configs as environment variables so I deleted hibernate.properties and set properties programmatically as following:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .addAnnotatedClass(WeatherResponse.class)
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", config.getString("user"))
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", config.getString("pass"))
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", config.getString("driver"))
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", config.getString("url"))
                .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", config.getString("dialect"));
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

But even though I am setting all properties I had in my properties file I am getting error:

```
16:49:55.338 [qtp550572371-22] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
16:49:55.340 [qtp550572371-22] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
16:49:55.379 [qtp550572371-22] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
16:49:55.486 [qtp550572371-22] WARN  o.h.e.j.c.i.ConnectionProviderInitiator - HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
16:49:55.487 [qtp550572371-22] WARN  o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
16:49:55.495 [qtp550572371-22] WARN  o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - /weather/new+york
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

I am using hibernate-core 5.2.2.Final and hibernate-annotations 3.5.6-Final and mysql-connection-java 6.0.3 and using Guice for dependency injection and am not using Spring.

Comment: are you using `@Configuration` ?

Comment: Not sure where I should use it, I am using Guice for dependency injection and not Spring

Comment: sorry I have only used it with spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this in the errors:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings
```

and I could fix issue by removing hibernate-annotations dependency since hibernate-core 5.2 already include it.